# Create Private Endpoint with Azure Cli in different resource group

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-virtual-network

I have a resource group for my vnet (rg-private-vnet) and one for my webapp and sql server (rg-webapp). Now I want to create a private endpoint for my SQl server in the rg-webapp.
This works in case the private endpoint is created in the resource group from he vnet. But I want it to be located in the resource group of the sql server.

I used:

```
 az network private-endpoint create --name $sqlPrivateEndpoint --resource-group $resourceGroupVnet --vnet-name $vnetName --subnet $sqlSubnetName --private-connection-resource-id $id --connection-name mySqlConnection  --group-id sqlServer
```

In case I use the rg-webapp I got the error:

```
(InvalidResourceReference) Resource /subscriptions/XXX/[...} referenced by resource /subscriptions/XXX/[...] was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region.
```

with the rg-private-vnet it works. In the azure portal it is no problem to create the endpoint in the rg-webapp resource group. I don't see any more parameters to create it in a diffrent rg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation you need to provide the resource id of the subnet to the `--subnet` parameter (instead of the subnet name) and skip the `--vnet-name` parameter if the subnet resides in a different resource group:

> `--subnet` Name or ID of an existing subnet. If name specified, also specify --vnet-name. If you want to use an existing subnet in other resource group or subscription, please provide the ID instead of the name of the subnet and do not specify the --vnet-name. ([az network private-endpoint | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/private-endpoint?view=azure-cli-latest#az_network_private_endpoint_create-required-parameters))